# Neo4j convert JSON results to array

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a simple query:

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n
```

It returns a JSON representation of the Node for each node.

```
{"id":1,"title":"Title 1", ...}
{"id":2,"title":"Title 2", ...}
```

But I want a table with property keys as headers.

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN theFunction(n)
=>
id|title  |description
 1|title 1|desc 1
 2|title 2|desc 2
```

Do you know if there is a function to do that?

I want to avoid having to list all the properties as in

```
MATCH (n:Node)
RETURN n.id as id, n.title as title, n.description as description...
```

Comment: I do not think that at the moment this is possible with the help of a cypher. If you want to do this, then you have to do it in two steps: first get on the backend a list of property names, then on the backend construct a query.